# how to remove border space from dropdown menu of bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty  new to bootstrap(using 3.3.7 version) and css and need to do some front-end editing of existing code.

I got the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select Fields
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style-type: none" ng-repeat="fieldObj in vm.gridOptions.columnDefs">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fieldObj.visible"> {{fieldObj.field}}
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-type: none">
                <button ng-click="vm.refreshGrid()">OK</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div></nav>
```

which results with the following :

[image]

Can I control the white space surrounding the list elements ?

Thanks

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: @לבנימלכה bootstrap version is 3.3.7

Comment: Just give your li a class and style it

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `ul` which by default takes browser specific styles

```
ul{
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   .dropdown-menu ul{
    padding-left:3px;
    }
```

instead the default `padding-left:40px;`

```css
.dropdown-menu ul{
padding-left:3px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select Fields
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style-type: none">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fieldObj.visible"> no
            </li>
           <li style="list-style-type: none">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fieldObj.visible"> yes
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-type: none">
                <button ng-click="vm.refreshGrid()">OK</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div></nav>
```